# Why ubuntu 15.10 still needs restart to update the kernel?

Tags: kernel, updates, restart, 15.10

I upgraded my system to ubuntu 15.10 dev a while ago and the kernel was 4.2.0-14.

A new update downloaded kernel 4.2.0-16 but "uname -a" still shows the current running kernel as 4.2.0-14.

```
Linux gedo 4.2.0-14-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 05:14:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I have this in my "/boot"

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1311387 Sep 21 17:36 abi-4.2.0-11-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1311906 Oct  2 01:49 abi-4.2.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1311978 Oct  8 11:15 abi-4.2.0-16-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184735 Sep 21 17:36 config-4.2.0-11-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184756 Oct  2 01:49 config-4.2.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184809 Oct  8 11:15 config-4.2.0-16-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Oct 17 19:36 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33492548 Oct  8 20:03 initrd.img-4.2.0-11-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33525010 Oct 16 18:39 initrd.img-4.2.0-14-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33673615 Oct 22 00:20 initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Jun 30  2014 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Aug 27 07:04 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Aug 27 07:04 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Aug 27 07:04 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3739218 Sep 21 17:36 System.map-4.2.0-11-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3740363 Oct  2 01:49 System.map-4.2.0-14-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3740437 Oct  8 11:15 System.map-4.2.0-16-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6720112 Sep 21 17:36 vmlinuz-4.2.0-11-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6720976 Oct  2 01:49 vmlinuz-4.2.0-14-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  6797680 Oct  8 11:15 vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
```

Comment: when the linux kernel boots up a bunch of things are loaded into memory, and a reboot will allow you to load the new version into memory, the kernel being the most basic component cannot load a new version without rebooting. Maybe you're wondering why this is needed in 4.2.x because this version comes with hot patching features integrated?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`

Comment: @FelipeReyes 4.X is not meant to need a restart after update. I think he is asking why it is needed?

Comment: Just BTW, this is on topic - 15.10 was released today. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/10/ubuntu-15-10-download-review-new-features Also what? Opinion based...?

Comment: "uname -a" shows 4.2.0-14

Comment: I had upgraded to the dev version before release, that's why I had 4.2.0-14 running.

Comment: @Tim http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/linux-kernel-4-0-new-features is this what you have in mind when you say that it doesn't need to be rebooted? "Install Kernel Updates Without Rebooting"

Comment: @FelipeReyes yes.

Comment: @Tim In this case a new deb package was installed, patches suitable to be loaded at runtime (hot patching) are not shipped by Ubuntu, some details about how kpatch works can be found at the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kpatch

Comment: @FelipeReyes So you are saying Ubuntu 15.10 does not support hot patching available in Kernel 4?

Comment: @Scarlet it does support it, but ubuntu is not releasing patches suitable for this, AFAIK they are just releasing new linux-image deb packages as they always did, that's why it requires a reboot

Comment: @FelipeReyes, you should consider turning your comment to an answer so OP can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Kernel 4 supported live patching, ubuntu did not provide the necessary updates for live patching of the kernel.

But now on Ubuntu 16.04, canonical has started to provide the live patches through [Canonical Livepatch Service](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/), all you need is to register (free for up to 3 systems), install the service

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

and enable it with your Token

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable [Token]
```

Afterwards, you will no longer need a restart.